What does \\ do in the Large environment?
For my thesis I use the following code for the title
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
   \begin{center}
      \begin{LARGE}
         \textbf{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.}\\
      \end{LARGE}
   \end{center}
\end{document}

By accident, I noticed that placing a \\ after the title line would change the line spacing of the the title. I thought it looked better this way, but I also want to understand why it did that, since normally \\ only creates a linebreak. Even after searching online for quite some time I couldnt find an explanation for this situation.
Can anybody explain to me what \\ does in the large environment, why it does that, and what other commands behave differently in environments?
Edit: I realized while testing its actually the center environment not the large environment that seems to create this behaviour.

I assume you are referring to the different linespacing shown by the following example:
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{LARGE}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.\\
\end{LARGE}
\end{center}
\begin{LARGE}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.\\
\end{LARGE}
\end{document}


First, note that no environment {LARGE} is defined by LaTeX. This happens to work here because of how environments are implemented, but in fact the code behaves as if you had typed
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begingroup
\LARGE
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.\\
\endgroup
\end{center}
\begingroup
\LARGE
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.\\
\endgroup
\end{document}

The odd result has therefore nothing to do with the (inexistent) environment {LARGE}; it has, however, to do with the environment {center}. In normal typesetting and ignoring the starred version or the optional argument, \\ is basically \unskip\nobreak\hfil\break, which forces a new line without ending the current paragraph.  On the other hand, within a {center} environment \\ is redefined, and it starts a new paragraph. The interaction here comes from the fact that while size-changing macros set also the line spacing, only the one active at the end of the current paragraph is actually used.
In the first case (within {center}) the \\ issues a new paragraph, so the baseline from \LARGE is used. In the second example, \\ issues a new line but the font size (and line spacing) is restored after \endgroup, so the normal baseline skip is used.

Okay thanks, that clears it up a bit. But if i use both {center} and {LARGE}, but without the \\, why does it not use the line spacing from {LARGE}? Why do I need to initate a linebreak for the line spacing in the previous line to be affected by the environment in which it was written?

@Sarius Like in the second case, the font size is restored after the group. In this case the paragraph is issued by \end{center}, but at that point the line spacing of \normalsize is active.

So in an environment like {center} I should (generally) always issue a new paragraph after a line to ensure that the line spacing applied is not reset by the \end{center}? And also font size is defined before the paragraph, while line spacing is defined after?

@Sarius no --- \end{center} ends the paragraph. The problem is that your (wrong) \end{LARGE} closes a group, and so restores the \normalsize before the center environment can do its job

@Sarius if you do use a size command as an environment always leave a blank line (rather than \\ ) before the \end
